# Hiding source in flash player

Tags: video, video-streaming, flash

I have to develop an application to play video online using flash player. All the video files have some cost to play/download and should not to be downloaded.

So now the problem is that when a user play a video he/she can view the source of flash player and then can download.

Please tell me how it is possible to hide or some other stuffs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can the user view the source of the Flash video if you use a front end video player? You typically have a video file, then an Flash player application that can browse videos and play them but not reveal the source.

Alternative, is a using a streaming server, like Flash media server, where the video is fed to the front end and not available as a single file.